# Can not identify the version of imported packages in my Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, version

Nothing seems to work when I try to identify the version of an imported package:

[image]

What is creating this problem?  What can I do about it?

I am using Python 3.7, Anaconda3 (2019) and Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

If I try it in notebooks.azure.com then everything works just fine:

```
import tensorflow
tensorflow.__version__
'1.12.2'
```

You can also try:

```
!pip show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.12.2
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
/..../
```